# Scanning all integers from the standard input. Assume that each input line is an integer and an empty line denotes end of input

Tags: c

Scanning all integers from the standard input. Assume that each input line is an integer and an empty line denotes end of input.

I need to scan integer from a line and if the entered input is empty then break.
Tried the following code but it gives weird output.

```
while (true)
        {
            char ch=getchar();
            printf("%c\n",ch);

            if(ch=='\n')
            {
                break;

            }
            //printf("%d\n",myInt);
            getchar();
        }
```

Kindly help!
Thanks

Comment: The second `getchar` call make you skip every second character. Which might lead you to skip the end of the line. And of course skip every other digit.

Comment: Also note that [`getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) returns an **`int`**, which is important when you check against `EOF` (which you really should).

Comment: What is the weird output and what output do you expect? For now, you print every second character read on its own line and check if the printed character is a newline.

Comment: Also please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your assumptions is given lines are integer so we can use below code.
[atoi](https://linux.die.net/man/3/atoi) function converts a `string` to `int`
[fgets](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) used to take string input from the user

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
  char str[1024]={};
  while( fgets(str, 1024, stdin) && str[0] != 0 && str[0] != '\n' ){
      int n = atoi(str);
      printf("%d\n", n);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Adding a small explanation would be a good idea

Comment: This is a nice compact solution but it doesn't have much error checking. Input like "abcd" will print 0 and input like "123abcd" will print 123. Don't know if that's acceptable for OP.

Comment: In the question it is mentioned that "Assume that each input line is an integer and an empty line"

Comment: @Mayur I did notice that "Assume ..." part. I just don't like writing code with such assumption about user input. Instead of `atoi` I think I would prefer `if (sscanf(input, "%d%n", &n, &cnt) != 1) exit(1);` and then check that all character was used, i.e. comparing `cnt` to `strlen`. Anyway - still a good compact solution so +1

Comment: @4386427 Comparing `cnt` to `strlen` is problematic as the `char` after the numeric input _may_ be a `'\n'` or 0.  A simple alternative is  `if (sscanf(input, "%d %n", &n, &cnt) != 1 || input[cnt])`  (add space and check the last character to see if non-white-space.)

Comment: @chux The compare would be `cnt == strlen -1` to make sure that all characters (except newline was used for the conversion).

Comment: @4386427 [That](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55137301/scanning-all-integers-from-the-standard-input-assume-that-each-input-line-is-an/55138949?noredirect=1#comment97021772_55138949) assumes `input` has a `'\n'` - a reasonable assumption yet goes against [this philosophy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55137301/scanning-all-integers-from-the-standard-input-assume-that-each-input-line-is-an/55138949?noredirect=1#comment97019197_55138949).  That is not certain with 1) long lines 2) end of `stdin` input and some other esoteric cases.

Comment: @chux True - there should also be a check for `'\n'` which can easilly be added. My point was simply that `atoi` silently accepts things that are not integers and that `sscanf` will give a way to know the number of chars used in the conversion.

Comment: @4386427 `sscanf(input, "%d%n", &n, &cnt)` is UB on when the converted   text input exceeds the `int` range.  Agree it is a step better than `atoi()`, but it also has its troubles too.

Answer (score 1):

I see a number of problems with your code:

1. The code doesn't read integers. It reads chars and print them. However, it only prints every second char as the return value of second `getchar` isn't used.
2. There is no error checking.
3. The return type of `getchar` is `int` - not `char`.

There are many ways to do what you want. It seems you want a solution using `getchar` so something like this could be a way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    while (1)
    {
        int n = 0;
        int multiplier = 1;
        int ch=getchar();
        if(ch=='\n') break;  // Empty line - stop reading integers
        if(ch=='-')
        {
            // Handle negative values
            multiplier = -1;
            ch=getchar();
            if(ch=='\n') exit(1);  // Error - unexpected newline
        }
        do
        {
            if(ch==EOF) exit(1); // Input error
            if (ch < '0' || ch > '9') exit(1); // Error - input is not a digit

            // "Add" current digit to the integer
            n = n * 10;
            n = n + ch - '0';

            ch=getchar();
        } while (ch != '\n');
        n = multiplier * n;
        printf("%d\n", n);
    }
    printf ("done\n");

    return 0;
}
```

A few comments:

The code above is not "production quality" but I wanted to keep the example simple. Some of the short commings are described below.

1. Just calling `exit(1)` on error is probably not what you want in a real application. At least you would print some error message first but in general you would add better error handling when dealing with user input.
2. The calculation of the integer value does not check for integer overflow. In a real application that is something you want to add.
3. The line `if(ch==EOF) exit(1);` isn't really needed because the next if-statement will catch that case and exit anyway. However, I added to show the difference between an input error and non-digit input.

Comment: what about negative values?

Comment: @Mayur Good point. Forgot about that. Answer updated.

Comment: Minor nits: OP did say "integers" which could include `long long` or beyond.  This code does have comer issues with `"+234" or " 123" or unnecessary `int` overflow with input like `"-2147483648"`.

Answer (score -2):

The simplest way is to just read integers and stop when there is no more integers to read. `scanf` works fine:

```
int n;
while (scanf("%d", &n) == 1) {
    // do something with integer n
}
// last scanf call failed to find an integer, so that's probably the end of input
```

This will not work if the input is in form "integers, empty line, more integers that should be ignored". In that case the code should be a bit more complex.

Comment: When `scanf("%d", &n)` encounter a line of input `"\n'"`, it will consume that whitespace and read more, waiting as needed.

Comment: Correct. It will only read integers ignoring any whitespace characters. It will only stop reading at non-integer non-whitespace character or end of input.

Answer (score -3):

Here is what I think you are looking for. In your original code snippet, you were only going to be printing every second integer because of the two getchar() functions, instead of removing that will read all characters. Then including the if statement before the print statement means you won't print out a newline character when printing the results.

```
            while (1)
            {
                char ch=getchar();
                if(ch=='\n')
                    break;
                printf("%c\n",ch);
            }
```

Comment: This still doesn't scan integers but chars